# How to install topicons plus extension in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I need to install topicons plus extension but ubuntu 22.04 not supported any one tell me the alternate extension for topicons plus

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 use `Extension Manager` (if its not already installed on your system then download it from `Ubuntu Software`) select `Browse`  and enter `TopiconsFix` which is the installable option.

The earlier versions are not supported in the current version of GNOME used for 22.04 but you could install the APT version of `Firefox` instead, if you really wanted the legacy version.